# About Construction a one-to-one function from $(a,b)$ onto $[a,b]$

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

This question asked to construct one-to-one function from $(a,b)$ onto $[a,b]$. I know there is a function but it seems the question to define this function explicitly. How this can be done?

**Edit**  I did first by transfinite induction But I was wrong. Thanks to user @ Arturo Magidin. He told me this wrong and he answered the question.

Comment: "Enumerate" means establishing a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto the set; that is not what you mean, so you should not use that word: neither set is denumerable, so neither set can be enumerated.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a construction. What's $f((a+b)/2)$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin,  Most of paper in set theory used. This is not my word

Comment: Not in my experience; you can talk about well-ordering it, but "enumerate" almost invariable implies countability. But you are welcome to point me to a specific paper to show me that this is indeed the case, so I can know better.

Comment: @aschepler, $(a+b)/2$ beloges to to set $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$

Comment: This is not a "construction"; you have waived your hands by essentially stating that you will establish an (unknown, unrepresented, unknowable) bijection between each of the sets and a particular cardinal, and then use them to define your desired bijection. That is not constructive. By contrast, you can do an **explicit**, **constructive** bijection fairly easily. If you are being asked to *construct* a bijection, and not merely to prove that one exists, then this doesn't do it (at least, it doesn't do it for me, and I suspect for whoever asked you to *construct* one).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, This is an exercise 4 in page 84 in the fndemental of real analysis by James Foran.

Comment: And what is that supposed to answer? Your use of "enumerate", or my comment about your attempt not being a "construction"?

Comment: "$(a,b)=\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\} \ \ \ ,   [a,b]=\{y_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}.$"  I have no freaking idea what this is supposed to mean or what you are trying to express.  This is ... it just makes utterly no sense.... at all.

Comment: @fleablood: a bijection to $x\colon\mathfrak{c}\to (a,b)$, representing $x(\alpha)$ as $x_{\alpha}$ similar to sequences, with $\mathfrak{c}$ (wrongly) viewed as an ordinal...

Comment: "(a+b)/2 beloges to to set {xξ:ξ<c}"  And $\sqrt 2$ belongs to $\mathbb R$.  But that doesn't tell us *what* $\sqrt 2$ specifically *is* that no other number is.  And you haven't told us *which* $x_\xi$ is mapped to $\frac {a+b}2$ (and which *no* other one is).

Comment: @Arturo: In the context of set theory the word "enumerate" often means any general well-ordering of the set, not necessarily a countable one. So one can say "enumerate $\Bbb R$ as $\{r_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Wow; that's definitely news to me, but you'd be better place than I to know that. That's... not good nomenclature, given that "ennumerable", presumably, still means "listable"/"countable"...

Comment: @Arturo: And people in computability might object, since "enumerable" can be understood as "recursively enumerable". :-)

Comment: "He told me this wrong". But you've removed the "this"; so now unless we go check the edit history, we don't know what you are talking about, or what "your attempt" that I mention in my answer refers to, since the new version of your post contains no attempt. There is no shame in makeing (and keeping visible) an error: the only shame would be to not learn from it going forward.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thank you so much for the nice advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would object to your attempt as not being a *construction*. It really amounts to nothing but saying "they both have the same cardinality, namely $\mathfrak{c}$, therefore there is a bijection between them."

To help you figure out how to give a *constructive* function, let me show you how to give an **explicit** bijection between $[0,1)$ and $(0,1)$:

Define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ by $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$. Note that $a_n\in (0,1)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Define $f\colon [0,1)\to (0,1)$ as follows:
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{2} &\text{if }x=0;\\
a_{n+1} &\text{if }x=a_n\text{ for some }n;\\
x &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Note that this is indeed a *construction*: I've told you exactly how to compute $f$ at any point, *explicitly*. If you give me an $x$, I can tell you *exactly* where it is mapped. Verify that $f$ is indeed a bijection.

Compare it with your definition: if I just said "find a bijection $g$ between $[0,1)$ and $\mathfrak{c}$; then find a bijection $h$ between $(0,1)$ and $\mathfrak{c}$; now define $f$ as $h^{-1}\circ g$" (which is essentially what you are doing), could you tell me what $f(\frac{1}{2})$ is? What $f(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$ is? What $f(0.25)$ is? No; but with the function I gave above, you can tell me exactly what the values are at any point. The $f$ I gave first is *constructive*; the one in this paragraph is *not* constructive.